# Gson RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory - null item to serialize leads to null pointer exception

Tags: serialization, gson

I am testing RuntimeTypeAdapterFactoryTest:

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/test/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactoryTest.java

which works well in the original example test case (testRuntimeTypeAdapter()):

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/test/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactoryTest.java#27

But if a registered type is null, I get an NPE exception in RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory. Extending the original example above:

```
static class Wallet {
    BillingInstrument payment;
}

Wallet wallet = new Wallet();
// wallet.payment = new Card("Jo", 123); // leave wallet.payment uninitialized.

gson.toJson(wallet); // throws NPE
```

If I initialize wallet.payment, then serialization works fine. Here's the stack trace:

```
Exception in thread, java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.me.test.RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java:218)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:91)
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:206)
at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:595)
...
```

Which points here:

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/typeadapters/RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java#218

Has anyone run into this and found a workaround? Gson is supposed to ignore serializing null values by default, so not sure why it's attempting to serialize wallet.payment in my example.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/google/gson/commit/1867457030d3c149566e95a019033cce4ff3cf90) which happened before version 2.4

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue.
This fix worked for me:

(RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory.java)

```
           @Override public void write(JsonWriter out, R value) throws IOException {
            if(value!=null) {
                Class<?> srcType = value.getClass();
                String label = subtypeToLabel.get(srcType);
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // registration requires that subtype extends T
                        TypeAdapter<R> delegate = (TypeAdapter<R>) subtypeToDelegate.get(srcType);
                if (delegate == null) {
                    throw new JsonParseException("cannot serialize " + srcType.getName()
                            + "; did you forget to register a subtype?");
                }
                JsonObject jsonObject = delegate.toJsonTree(value).getAsJsonObject();
                if (jsonObject.has(typeFieldName)) {
                    throw new JsonParseException("cannot serialize " + srcType.getName()
                            + " because it already defines a field named " + typeFieldName);
                }
                JsonObject clone = new JsonObject();
                clone.add(typeFieldName, new JsonPrimitive(label));
                for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> e : jsonObject.entrySet()) {
                    clone.add(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
                }
                Streams.write(clone, out);
            }else{
                out.nullValue();
            }
```